# ruby watir classic won't authenticate proxy

Tags: ruby, authentication, proxy, watir-webdriver, watir-classic

I try to open internet explorer via watir-webdriver with my code:

```
require "watir-webdriver"


profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
profile.proxy = Selenium::WebDriver::Proxy.new :http => 'http://username:password@xx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxxx', :ssl => 'http://username:password@xx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxxx'
```

And I get this error stating something about the  I'm guessing? 
This is what it reads:

```
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/profile.rb:205:in `Integer': invalid value for Integer(): "//username:password@xx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxxx" (ArgumentError)
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/profile.rb:205:in `set_manual_proxy_preference'
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/profile.rb:176:in `proxy='
    from test1.rb:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: I tried '.start' method as well...

Comment: I can't help you with the watir-classic code, but I would encourage you to evaluate updating to watir-webdriver as that is where all of the project's continued development focus is.

Comment: I used webdrver for ie and had the same problem @titusfortner

Comment: That I can help you with. Update your question by adding the webdriver stack trace and we'll get it figured out.

Comment: @titusfortner I changed my question around, and this is the error i'm getting when trying to authenticate a proxy with firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I can explain the error at least. You can't pass in basic authentication to a proxy url because the code expects that a colon in the string is distinguishing a host from a port (which needs to be an integer.

I do not have much experience with using proxies with Selenium. Poking around on the internet for the problem give suggestions such as setting `signon.autologin.proxy` to true in your designated Firefox profile, or adding the Firefox `autoauth` extension. Essentially you can save your password once manually in your profile, and then automated tests won't have to input it.